# How to create multiple threads in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I recently started learning jmeter. Please help me
How can i create a multiple thread groups which performs same actions but with different credentials.
Issue is - in the current application i am testing ,if 5 users hit the refresh btn at the same time its crashing the system. 
so my Requirement is - Login with 2 different users and hit refresh button

I created 2 thread groups -for user A and user B but when i run the test plan its executing simultaneously.its checking multiple threads with same credentials of user A ,Which is not my requirement. What is the way to deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following:

1. Use single Thread Group, you don't need separate Thread Groups as they are designed to represent different **groups** of virtual users.
2. Make sure you use different credentials for users A and B. Normally people use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for keeping users credentials so JMeter threads (virtual users) could read CSV file and pick up login and password combinations from there
3. To ensure that users A and B (or whatever will be the number) "refresh" the page at exactly the same moment - use [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)

Comment: will try it . Thanks Dmitri !!

Comment: Hi, I have created thread as you mentioned above. 
1) Created thread group of 1 with 3 iterations(for 3 users)
2) Added csv data file and set config element
3) Added the actions recorded by blazemeter into the testplan
4) Added listeneres
5) Executed the testplan

Result : All users are still taking my first user (user-A) credentials - i recorded my action with user-A only

Do i need to set anything else ? where did i made a mistake?

Thanks

Comment: You need to replace hard-coded recorded user-name with the variables from CSV file

Comment: yes i have changed the username with variable names in my file but still its not reading

Comment: Update your question with screenshots of your HTTP Request, CSV Data Set config and *jmeter.log* file contents